# Yii2 DetailView widget - access data with role

Tags: yii, yii2

This is the query I am using to find user:

```
$model = User::find()->with('role')->where(['id' => $id])->one();
```

And the **DetailView widget**:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'first_name',
            'email:email',
            'password',
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

I need to access role name. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a getRole in your user model:

```
public function getRole() 
{
        $role = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select('itemname')
                ->from('AuthAssignment')
                ->where('userid=:id', array(':id'=>$this->id))
                ->queryScalar();

        return $role;
}
```

And then use direct in your widget `$model->getRole()`

Hope it will solve your problem.